# Replacing text values with a number

Tags: r, replace, sum

I have exported some survey data and have a couple of columns that are currently textual descriptions:

Note: I added the sum column. Some of the columns in my data have N/As which I will convert to 0s for the sums.

```
fire_ring1 <- c("ash", "rock", "ash")
fire_ring2 <- c("rock", "metal", "ash")
sum <- c("2", "2", "2")
df <- data.frame(fire_ring1, fire_ring2, sum)
```

Instead of the text I would like to convert the values to 1s so that I can sum them across columns, I am interested in total number and not type.

Thanks

Comment: A string will evaluate to `TRUE`. `sum(c(TRUE,TRUE))` is 2.

Comment: @mhovd I am not following the conversion to logical.

Comment: Your logic of *"1s so that I can sum them"* doesn't make sense to me. Can you explain how that should look given this data?

Comment: For instance, without any conversion, `rowSums(df == "ash")` returns `[1] 1 0 2`, which seems pretty clear to me.